Rewrite rules with typeclass constraints
There's been a couple of previous questions about rewrite rules that have typeclass constraints, but they seem to involve higher-rank polymorphism. Here, I have a much more "vanilla" situation with no higher-rank types and a typeclass constraint that should actually already be satisfied by the type of the left-hand side:
class C a where
    op :: a -> a

newtype Foo tag w = Foo{ runFoo :: w }

instance (Monoid w) => C (Foo tag w) where
    op = id

opSpecial :: (Monoid w) => Foo () w -> Foo () w
opSpecial _ = Foo mempty

{-# RULES
      "op/special" forall w. forall. op @(Foo () w) = opSpecial
  #-}

(this is a very minimized example, imagine that opSpecial is extensionally equivalent but operationally superior to the generic op)
The rewrite rule fails to typecheck with the following error message:
rewrite-context.hs:13:55: error: [GHC-39999]
    • Could not deduce ‘Monoid w’ arising from a use of ‘opSpecial’
      from the context: C (Foo () w)
        bound by the RULE "op/special" at rewrite-context.hs:13:7-63
      Possible fix:
        add (Monoid w) to the context of the RULE "op/special"
    • In the expression: opSpecial
      When checking the rewrite rule "op/special"
   |
13 |       "op/special" forall w. forall. op @(Foo () w) = opSpecial

Note that Monoid w is already a constraint on the polymorphic instance forall w. C (Foo tag w), so I would expect it to be satisfied for every invocation of op @(Foo () w) already. But OK, maybe there could be some overlapping/incoherent instances that wouldn't have that constraint. Nevertheless, what is the syntax for adding the constraint to the rewrite rule? The GHC manual section on rewrite rules doesn't seem to describe any way of add(ing) Monoid w to the context of the RULE.

Hm. Well, forall (v :: Monoid w => Foo () w). op v = opSpecial v appears to at least be correct syntax. Not sure whether it has the right semantics, especially whether the eta expansion would prevent this rule from firing in some case you care about.

Related idea: perhaps you could make something like opProxy :: C a => Proxy a -> a -> a; opProxy _ = op and rules that add and then remove proxies, e.g. op = opProxy Proxy and forall (p :: Monoid w => Proxy (Foo () w)). opProxy p = opSpecial or something like that.

One workaround I've found (and actually it's not 100% clear to me yet if it's a workaround or the proper solution) is to define the generic op by way of a toplevel function that makes its Monoid w context direct:
instance (Monoid w) => C (Foo tag w) where
    op = opGeneric

{-# NOINLINE opGeneric #-}
opGeneric :: (Monoid w) => Foo tag w -> Foo tag w
opGeneric = id

(we have to mark opGeneric NOINLINE so that a rewrite rule has a chance to trigger on it)
Then, the rewrite rule can be changed to mention opGeneric instead of the overloaded op on its LHS:
opSpecial :: (Monoid w) => Foo () w -> Foo () w
opSpecial _ = Foo mempty

{-# RULES
      "op/special" forall w. forall. opGeneric @w @() = opSpecial
  #-}

